# NSAttributedString (NSMuttableAttributeString), использование семейства шрифтов

Tags: ios, шрифты

Есть ли способ добавить в качестве атрибута для `NSAttributedString` (`NSMuttableAttributeString`) не просто шрифт, а семейство шрифтов для `range`? Клиент-серверное приложение получает форматированное в HTML описание продукта, необходимо сохранить размеры, толщину, курсив (если есть) у шрифта, но заменить его семейство. Если указать в качестве атрибута шрифт с размером, то форматирование, связанное с размерами и толщиной шрифта стирается.

UPDATED: Решил с помощью костыля

```
let d : NSMutableAttributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: ((здесь html текст).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!, 
options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], 
documentAttributes: nil)

d.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, 
inRange: NSMakeRange(0, d.length), 
options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions()) {
value, range, stop in
let oldFont = value as! UIFont

    var newFontName : String
    if oldFont.fontName.lowercaseString.containsString("bold") {
       newFontName = Decorator.fontArray["Bold"]!
    } else if oldFont.fontName.lowercaseString.containsString("italic") {
       newFontName = Decorator.fontArray["Italic"]!
    } else {
       newFontName = Decorator.fontArray["Regular"]!
    }

    let newFont = UIFont(name: newFontName, size: 14)

    d.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value : newFont!, range : range)
}
```

Где `Decorator.fontArray` это `Dictionary<String, String>` с ключами с названиями типов шрифтов, значениями - названиями шрифтов для этих типов. Не сработает если в названии шрифта не будет bold или italic, а значит вопрос остается в силе ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу два варианта:

1) менять шрифт в html до того, как вы его конвертируете в string

```
var source: NSString = "Text <strong>Here</strong>"
source = source.stringByAppendingString("<style>strong{font-family: 'Avenir-Roman';font-size: 14px;}</style>")
do {
let d:NSMutableAttributedString =
    try NSMutableAttributedString(data: source.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
    options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(int:Int32(NSUTF8StringEncoding))],
    documentAttributes: nil)
    var label:UILabel!
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100,0,200,100))
    label.attributedText = d
    self.view.addSubview(label)
} catch {
}
```

2) брать каждый символ отдельно и менять на нем шрифт, оставляя остальные атрибуты

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString
{
    func convertFontTo(font: UIFont)
    {
        var range = NSMakeRange(0, 0)

        while (NSMaxRange(range) < length)
        {
            let attributes = attributesAtIndex(NSMaxRange(range), effectiveRange: &range)
            if let oldFont = attributes[NSFontAttributeName]
            {
                let newFont = UIFont(descriptor: font.fontDescriptor().fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(oldFont.fontDescriptor().symbolicTraits), size: font.pointSize)
                addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range: range)
            } else {
                addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: range)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использовать вот так:

```
let desc = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: someNSAttributedString)
desc.convertFontTo(UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16))
```

Comment: в html нет названия шрифта - там есть теги - <b></b> и так далее. Они преобразуются в конкретный шрифт, который предустановлен по умолчанию (в IDE, в классе NSMutableAttributedString - не знаю) и этот атрибут уже не хранится в строке, он хранится в названии шрифта (OpenSans-Bold - например). Форматировать html дело неблагодарное, придется накладывать серьезный парсер, и не факт что будет результат, а второй способ отпадает, так как атрибут (толщины, курсива, гиперссылки) не хранится, а значит форматирование строки опять теряется

Answer (score 0):

Я все таки нашел решение, весьма элегантное

```
extension UILabel {
    func setHTMLFromString(text: String) {
        let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>", text) as String
        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: modifiedFont.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
        documentAttributes: nil)

        self.attributedText = attrStr
    }
}
```

Признаюсь честно ошибся насчет пасера html, все вышло куда проще

Comment: так что со ста рублями будете делать? :)

Comment: ))) вроде же прибавил)